# @Autowired with JUnit5

Tags: java, spring, autowired, junit5

I'm using JUnit5 and need to inject a bean managed by Spring (transactionManager), but I can't have the @Autowired work. 
This is what I did :

First I declared the beans in an xml file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">


<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="com.dummy.myerp.business.impl.TransactionManager"
 factory-method="getInstance">
<constructor-arg ref="txManagerMYERP"/>
</bean>


    <!-- PlatformTransactionManager pour le DataSource MYERP -->
    <bean id="txManagerMYERP" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMYERP"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSourceMYERP" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <constructor-arg value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9032/db_myerp" />
        <property name="username" value="usr_myerp"/>
        <property name="password" value="myerp"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="applicationContextProvider"
          class="com.dummy.myerp.technical.util.spring.ApplicationContextProvider"/>

</beans>
```

And in the test class, I loaded the context with `@ContextConfiguration`:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:transactionContextTest.xml")
public class ComptabiliteManagerImplTest extends AbstractBusinessManager {

    private static ComptabiliteManagerImpl manager = new ComptabiliteManagerImpl();

    private static TransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Autowired
    public void setTransactionManager(TransactionManager transactionManager) {
        ComptabiliteManagerImplTest.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

    @BeforeAll
    private static void injectMockDao() {
        DaoProxy daoProxyMock = mock(DaoProxy.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        AbstractBusinessManager.configure(null, daoProxyMock, transactionManager);
    }
```

The problem is: the TransactionManager is not loaded. When I run some tests that require it, I get a NullPointerException.

What did I do wrong?

EDIT : Instead of using @Autowired, I tried to retrieve the bean from the context like this :

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:transactionContextTest.xml")
public class ComptabiliteManagerImplTest extends AbstractBusinessManager {

    private static ComptabiliteManagerImpl manager = new ComptabiliteManagerImpl();


    private static ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("transactionContextTest.xml");
    private static TransactionManager transactionManager = (TransactionManager) context.getBean("transactionManager");


    @BeforeAll
    private static void injectMockDao() {
        DaoProxy daoProxyMock = mock(DaoProxy.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        AbstractBusinessManager.configure(null, daoProxyMock, transactionManager);
    }
```

It works, but it's kind of a work arround and it makes clear that the issue is with the annotation @Autowired. Is there a clean and easy way to use @Autowired with JUnit5?

Comment: For JUnit 4 yes, but with JUnit 5 are you sure?

Comment: can you try to load it through code instead of annotation `MessageSource resources 
      = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        "classpathxmlapplicationcontext-internationalization.xml");`

Comment: @RunWith is not needed in Junit 5, @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) will work and he is already doing it.

Comment: okay i think this might be the issue, make this method `injectMockDao` as instance and annotate `@Before` and i don't think it is because of `@Autowire`

Comment: have your tried my approach @JulienBerthoud?

Comment: @Deadpool, yes I made an edit to my post. I could indeed retrieve the bean from the context with code instead of annotation, and this works. But i'm not sure about what you meant with "make the method injectMockDao as instance". I need a method to call the other method AbstractBusinessManager.configure()

Comment: I mean remove that staic keyword in injectmockdao method, and use @Before instead of '@BeforeAll'

Comment: @Before is not a valid annotation in JUnit5, https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/. Anyway, I found a work arround, so better than nothing.